# Quick rebus – Blink and you'll miss it!

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

The answer is the name of a place.

> [image]

Comment: is the centre symbol a comma separating two parts, or a part of the rebus itself?

Comment: @AHKieran Just one answer, the comma's part of it.

Comment: Can you give me another hint?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

i guess the answer is:

> Reno,Nevada

because

> first symbol is called a *half-rest* in american english, we take the half of *rest*  either *re* or *st*. 
>  second symbol is called *half note* in american english, same logic as before *no* or *te*  
>  combining the 2 we got *reno* or *rete* or *stno* or *stte*. 
>  the only place within these 4 is **Reno** 
>  3rd symbol is a simple coma 
>  4th symbol is a *quarter note* same logic, we take **N** 
>  last symbol is simply **V** 
>  we then got **Reno,NV**  (Reno, Nevada)

Comment: Yep, this is it!